# Is a Single Texture Cube Map Possible?

Tags: opengl, textures, cubemap

I'm currently developing a test project to explore OpenGL 3 texturing abilities. I have a simple cube, made of 8 vertices and 36 indices. I want each of the cubes faces to have a different texture, so I devised this texture:

[image: Cubemap?]

I made it obvious which sections I want visible (I hope...). In Direct3D, I once made a skybox, and I used a cubemap. However, I had to split it into 6 different textures. This is annoying and hard to manage, it would be nice to have just one texture. Is this even possible? I read somewhere that I could do this by duplicating vertices, is that a good idea? Someone else said I could do it in the shader, but that also baffles me...

Comment: A cube texture **is** a single texture. A texture is *not* a 2D image; it is a container of *multiple* images. Those can be mipmaps, [cubemap faces and their mipmaps](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Cubemap_Texture), [array layers and their mipmaps](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Array_Texture), or [arrays of cubemap faces and their mipmaps](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Cubemap_Texture#Cubemap_array_textures). These are all stored in *one* texture.

Comment: If '6 different textures' (or 6 different texture images) are 'annoying and hard to manage', then I'd have to say you have issues in your project well beyond what packing things into a single image will fix.  I'd worry about the root issue much more than the symptom; being able to handle a cubemap, or bundles of texture images, effectively will be _much_ more useful to you in the long run.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki It's not that I can't manage them, its that I'd rather not. It's easier to have 1 paper with your shopping list than 6 papers each with a different portion of your list; it's easier to have 1 texture than 6 textures. There is less margin for stuff like missing textures to happen, and it keeps things nice an tidy.

Comment: @smoth190: What "6 papers" are you talking about? DDS can store all of the cubemap faces in the same file. And once loaded into memory, they're all in the same texture object. So what 6 things are you having a problem with?

Comment: @NicolBolas DDS would be great, except this is OpenGL...

Comment: @smoth190: DDS is an image format and nothing more than that. There's no law that says you can't load DDS images into an OpenGL texture. Indeed, this is commonly done; there are even [libraries that will do it for you](http://glsdk.sourceforge.net/docs/html/index.html).

Comment: @NicolBolas Ok, thats interesting, however if all I have to do is change the way I send vertices to the shader to get the desired affect, the DDS format is useless to me.

Comment: @smoth190: Except that it would have seams in it at the edges, where it can't filter between cubemap faces. Proper cubemaps are seamless if you activate seamless cubemapping. Also, doing things like projective texturing with cubemaps is far more difficult without actual cubemaps.

Comment: @NicolBolas But I believe I have already said, this isn't for _actual_ cube mapping, its just a way to get a cube mapped with 6 different textures on each face. I don't need any of that seamless stuff or anything. The only reason I even mentioned cubemapping was to make it easier to visualize my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to do it with a single texture, the easiest thing to do is UV map your sky cube model to that texture layout.  Then, you can use a normal texturing shader.

Comment: You won't get the special cubemap hardware features though, such as being able to simply pass a 3D vector and have the hardware figure out the UVs, or bilinear texture filtering across the face boundaries.

Comment: Of course.  It IS the easiest method, though.

Comment: What I'm trying to do isn't create an actual cubemap, but just to make my job easier by having only one texture. A just want a cube with 6 different textures, it is not for a sky or anything. I can't seem to figure out how to wrap that around with only 8 vertices, therefor 8 UV values.

Comment: So...use indexing.  Just because there are only eight vertex positions doesn't mean there has to be 8 UV positions.

Comment: @Boreal How would I do this? My vertex array is made of structs of 6 elements, x, y, z, u, and v. The index array is an array of unsigned ints. Am I doing it wrong, or is there just an alternative?

Comment: The way you usually do this is with a position list, a UV list, and two indices per vertex.  I don't know if you can use 2 index buffers explicitly in OpenGL, so you have to build the vertex buffer from that data manually.  Just look at how you would load an OBJ model.

Comment: @Boreal Interesting, I will look into this. Thank you, this is the kind of thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get a cube map texture starting with that image on disk, then just extend your texture loader to slice up that image into individual cube map faces!

Comment: I'm still confused at how I would set up the UV normals. I only have 8 vertices.

Comment: If you are using a cube map texture, then that is not a problem — you specify the texture coordinates like normals, in three dimensions, and as Nathan Reed mentioned, the GPU will figure out the necessary 2D positions. If you were trying to use a 2D texture, *then* you would have to duplicate vertices to get distinct texture coordinates.

Comment: Hm, I see. Well I don't want to use a cubemap because it isn't needed. However, duplicated vertices can build up if I have a lot of these cubes. Which one is less of a performance hit?

Comment: I don't know, sorry. I don't have a lot of experience with OpenGL performance considerations.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to stack the cube faces vertically in a single image, and either split the original bitmap in software, or offset the pointer to the image data when uploading the textures to the GPU. (usually by: `bytesPerPixel * width * (height \ 6) * faceIndex`).

A custom cube mapping shader is not difficult, selecting the largest component of the view ray as z, calculate texture coordinates using this formula: `ray.xy/ray.z * 0.5 + 0.5`. To select an image, divide v by 6, and add 1/6 * the face's index. Filtering across the edges might be more of a challenge.